# android HttpClient remove dash from post string

Tags: android, httpclient

I have to post timestamp or other string with dash " - " like "2015-09-26 13:09:25"

But after post from android using HttpClient in server i receive timestamp=2015 09 26 13:09:25

Basically removed dash by android app

```
try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        String ts=URLEncoder.encode("2015-09-26 13:09:25", "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strUrl);


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStamp", "2015-09-26 13:09:25"));


        UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(json);
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStamp", ts)); but this is also not working

Comment: if you use urlencode timestamp will look like this. "2015-09-26+13%3A09%3A25" means its not removing dash. and server side i recieve space " " instead of dash " - "

Comment: The best way to pass date is milliseconds and convert that milliseconds with whatever format you want at sever side,

Comment: Show us the code on the server side application. This code doesn not remove the dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to pass date in milliseconds and convert it in whatever format you want at sever side.

For e.g

```
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStamp", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: my bad server issue android post is working server remove the dash